# How to establish a connection to AWS Device farm Remote session endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-device-farm

I tried to create AWS Device farm remote session, which i am able to do it successfully. The response JSON of the created remote session has an endpoint (wss) and the hostAddress(IP). Rather then login into AWS device farm to interact with the device. I wanted to provide remote access directly on my own web page (I am not sure whether its possible). Hoping it can be rendered under a canvas tag.

Though i do not have experience on the socket, i just tried some sample code to connect with the received Web Socket URL.

```
var wsUri = "wss://devicefarm-interactive.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?X-Amz-Date=*&X-Amz-Credential=*&X-Amz-Algorithm=*&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=*&X-Amz-Security-Token=*";
var websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
websocket.send('ping');
```

Below is the error the console.
*Connection closed before receiving a handshake response.*

[image: error image]

Any sample links to implement would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to reproduce that error. I looked for examples of using the web socket connection using the networking tab after inspecting the page in chrome(since it has a web socket debugger built into it) which will show the following:

[image: web console google pixel]

Basically how that appears to be working is it's sending us a constant stream of images.

When I copy as cURL command this is the result

`curl 'wss://devicefarm-interactive.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?X-Amz-Date=20190518T211708Z&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAIGY76PSQXN5NZ3UA%2F20190518%2Fus-west-2%2Fdevicefarm%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&arn=arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%111122223333%3Asession%3A8f4af46d-8f86-4dcc-8324-e691ce3723f3%2F6b4dc632-188f-45b9-be32-3e9aa6881ed3%2F00000&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=39b45e1489d44dfcb904d58e59e985844416061a828aa75750d5a67db36c55dd&X-Amz-Security-Token=someTokenValue&path=video' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Origin: https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Key: 60RGfCwWuULib6NmeoC2fA==' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36' -H 'Upgrade: websocket' -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Connection: Upgrade' -H 'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13' --compressed`

When I did the following CLI command I get the endpoint back:

`aws devicefarm get-remote-access-session --arn arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:session:8f4af46d-8f86-4dcc-8324-e691ce3723f3/6b4dc632-188f-45b9-be32-3e9aa6881ed3/00000 --region us-west-2 --query remoteAccessSession.endpoint`

```
"wss://devicefarm-interactive.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?X-Amz-Date=20190518T212323Z&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAIU5CA7GBP5IEBR6Q%2F20190518%2Fus-west-2%2Fdevicefarm%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&arn=arn%3Aaws%3Adevicefarm%3Aus-west-2%3A111122223333%3Asession%3A8f4af46d-8f86-4dcc-8324-e691ce3723f3%2F6b4dc632-188f-45b9-be32-3e9aa6881ed3%2F00000&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=aaaaqaqbbbb4e9f09b7312715c295a11b77bc0d9e7b21dcb61422a61f78a1f&X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEFcaDD2E90%2Bsp3i%2F%2F8cBbyKDA2EGKkFYSvXDR%2Fb7LfS%2FpQEPCWFVhe9eCOTSussvshjldx69CEFvVgV3JYtOvm2yu0UMVAxlDYlujvpMfSNwLx7FH%2B42k9qGYuvy5dQbVLg%2F%2BCRuyK9OjCxpD5pUfQ9b81U6LawcI2I1CekXeTgapRuTK9tCPcGtNOlxAvWQUVlyDGTtmqjz7vRlostquMoenNr9UB1v8jx0NSo1YIlrgY8YvZV2o5pcbYiI9I9CBD0%2F3snJZAyQtmPZkMT9gr9hI0jgX1X5MlOuarFmm%2F2Sn%2FH8L3ewMQXhvuho3OTNZTISBmUgJAbZSmQcazuDmjXqPkoNpYYcUb92vd2w5MbRfFSa5SHHXUMVcE5Wsop3BzwJyj%2FNyl59BdjFWdo82NgSFP6OBjYLjiux3hR2dx86ILJ9tfNMNfq0WXzL3Z%2BqecwMTxlxrLfZmPftsUDaO5RPtOP9uuI%2BPjfIOWOV7uFy9GjKG4HKFY%2BZVGgWhb1fVVG7%2BYHbPxgMaAKI3YJqmM9IIy8%2FdCjL74HnBQ%3D%3D%7CMjA1LjI1MS4yMzMuMTc5"
```

which appears to be signed. Using wscat I tried to connect to it.

```
endpoint=$(aws devicefarm get-remote-access-session --arn arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:session:8f4af46d-8f86-4dcc-8324-e691ce3723f3/6b4dc632-188f-45b9-be32-3e9aa6881ed3/00000 --region us-west-2 --query remoteAccessSession.endpoint)

wscat -c $endpoint
```

**Error**:
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/wscat/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:455
    throw new Error(`Invalid URL: ${this.url}`);`

I'll need to spend some more time on this later but I think some of this content is helpful so I posted it.

Comment: Have you ever managed to solve this? I have the same issue, I want an URL that I can open to interact with the device screen.